# How to import (or add as dependency) the CKEditor 5 Custom build

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I created a Custom build using the UI:
https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

After downloading the zip, how can I add it as a dependency to my Angular project?
I followed this tutorial:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html

I have the build ready, so every dependency is installed.
How can i use it in my Angular project?

First I tried to add the .tgz as a dependency:
npm install ./ck5editor.tgz  but no use.

Comment: My guess is that you would need to make it a module first, then you can install it, but definitely not from the .tgz file.